# Check if a $f \in U$

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

> Let $U$ be a subspace where $U = \{ f \in Abb(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}) |\; \forall\; x \in \mathbb{R}: f(x) = -f(-x)\}$ and $f_0: x \mapsto \frac{1}{1+x^2}$.
> Check if $b: x \mapsto |x|$ is in $f_0 + U$.

When I write out $f_0 + U = \frac{1}{1+x^2} + f(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2} -f(-x)$ I can't see a way to bring the function $b$ into the game. I know I can write $b = x$, $x \geq 0$ and $b = -x$, $x<0$ or when I plot $f(x) = x$ which is in U, I can see that it matches the graph for $x>0$ but not when $f_0$ comes into play. I am not even sure how to tackle this problem.

EDIT: $Abb(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ means all maps from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$

Comment: How do you define $Abb(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})?$

Comment: @SahibaArora Abb = "Abbildungen" = probably all maps $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$

Comment: $b=f_0+(b-f_0)$. Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $b \in f_0+U,$ then $b-f_0 \in U.$ That is $(b-f_0)(x)=(f_0-b)(-x).$ Now $$(b-f_0)(x)=|x|-\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$ and $$(f_0-b)(-x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}-|-x|=\frac{1}{1+x^2}-|x|,$$ therefore $$|x|-\frac{1}{1+x^2}=\frac{1}{1+x^2}-|x|$$ which implies $$|x|=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$but this is only true for exactly $2$ values of $x \in \mathbb{R}.$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If $b \in f_0 + U$, then there is an $f \in U$ for which
$$
b(x) = f_0(x) + f(x) \implies f(x) = b(x) - f_0(x).
$$